# Address arithmetic in Ida Pro

Tags: assembly, arm, address

Can someone tell more about address arithmetic in Ida? I were looking for assembly instructions and saw this

```
LDR R0, =(byte_255914C - 0xC63D50)
```

I understood right that in r0 will be an address which calculates like 255914C - C63D50 = it will be 18F53FC? And why not directly to write 18F53FC?

Comment: what's happening later with R0? please edit and add a longer snippet